# Constantly getting timeouts on code almost identical to that in the Stellar Docs

Tags: transactions

I have created a simple function, which is basically almost identical to the one in the stellar documentation "Sending and receiving custom assets" found [here](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/issuing-assets.html#try-it-out)

I constantly get error 504 timeouts ... it's basically timing out every single time I try it.

Note - the secret keys referred to in the function declaration relate to funded accounts on the stellar testnet.

My function differs from the stellar one as follows:
- it has "fee:200" and "fee:500" in the .TransactionBuilder calls [as now recommended by stellar I believe) (I experimented with values here, no difference found, still get 504 timeout).

```
function TryStellarEntireScenario ( SK_Issuer , SK_Distributor ,SK_userSender  ,SK_userReceiver ) {
// the SK's are the Secret keys  

var server = new StellarSdk.Server('https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org');
StellarSdk.Network.useTestNetwork();
// The other set-ups from the server are done further up this source code file

// Keys for accounts to issue and receive the new asset

var issuingKeys = StellarSdk.Keypair
.fromSecret(SK_Issuer);
var receivingKeys = StellarSdk.Keypair
.fromSecret(SK_Distributor);


// Create an object to represent the new asset
var astroDollar = new StellarSdk.Asset('AstroDollar', issuingKeys.publicKey());

// First, the receiving account must trust the asset
server.loadAccount(receivingKeys.publicKey())
.then(function(receiver) {
 var transaction = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(receiver, {fee:200})
   // The `changeTrust` operation creates (or alters) a trustline
   // The `limit` parameter below is optional
   .addOperation(StellarSdk.Operation.changeTrust({
     asset: astroDollar,
     limit: '1000'
   }))
   // setTimeout is required for a transaction
   .setTimeout(100)
   .build();
 transaction.sign(receivingKeys);
 return server.submitTransaction(transaction);
})

// Second, the issuing account actually sends a payment using the asset
.then(function() {
 return server.loadAccount(issuingKeys.publicKey())
})
.then(function(issuer) {
 var transaction = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(issuer, {fee:500})
   .addOperation(StellarSdk.Operation.payment({
     destination: receivingKeys.publicKey(),
     asset: astroDollar,
     amount: '10'
   }))
   // setTimeout is required for a transaction
   .setTimeout(100)
   .build();
 transaction.sign(issuingKeys);
 return server.submitTransaction(transaction);
})
.catch(function(error) {
 console.error('Error!', error);
});

}
```

Here is the error log:

```
Error! { Error: Request failed with status code 504
    at createError (C:\Users\mhard\MH_DB_Dev\SimpleExample\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (C:\Users\mhard\MH_DB_Dev\SimpleExample\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:18:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (C:\Users\mhard\MH_DB_Dev\SimpleExample\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:201:11)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
  config:
   { adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
     transformRequest: { '0': [Function: transformRequest] },
     transformResponse: { '0': [Function: transformResponse] },
     timeout: 60000,
     xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
     xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
     maxContentLength: -1,
     validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
     headers:
      { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'X-Client-Name': 'js-stellar-sdk',
        'X-Client-Version': '0.15.3',
        'User-Agent': 'axios/0.18.0',
        'Content-Length': 311 },
     method: 'post',
     url: 'https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/transactions',
     data: 'tx=AAAAAO6dqZWvM8smCFbXvnceXkb4OfCRjVxF1BwPz9hkEHlfAAAAyAADiukAAAABAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAF1VFzMAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAGAAAAAkFzdHJvRG9sbGFyAAAAAADCpKTKB1QZ83KqY5yS1pJuBj%2FkizTq9IfSurr4axwabAAAAAJUC%2BQAAAAAAAAAAAFkEHlfAAAAQHGAvUrL7Lj1veTs2YEAV3ZkccixLYdl6Z3ZIJveuk2x32YWqhHOk3BCIcY8m4MpdO8nuHF%2BysVHwhD8P8jGLAQ%3D' },
  request:
   ClientRequest {
     domain: null,
     _events:
      { socket: [Function],
        abort: [Function],
        aborted: [Function],
        error: [Function],
        timeout: [Function],
        prefinish: [Function: requestOnPrefinish] },
     _eventsCount: 6,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     output: [],
     outputEncodings: [],
     outputCallbacks: [],
     outputSize: 0,
     writable: true,
     _last: true,
     upgrading: false,
     chunkedEncoding: false,
     shouldKeepAlive: false,
     useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
     sendDate: false,
     _removedConnection: false,
     _removedContLen: false,
     _removedTE: false,
     _contentLength: null,
     _hasBody: true,
     _trailer: '',
     finished: true,
     _headerSent: true,
     socket:
      TLSSocket {
        _tlsOptions: [Object],
        _secureEstablished: true,
        _securePending: false,
        _newSessionPending: false,
        _controlReleased: true,
        _SNICallback: null,
        servername: 'horizon-testnet.stellar.org',
        npnProtocol: undefined,
        alpnProtocol: false,
        authorized: true,
        authorizationError: null,
        encrypted: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 9,
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: null,
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'horizon-testnet.stellar.org',
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: false,
        domain: null,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _bytesDispatched: 592,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: undefined,
        _server: null,
        ssl: null,
        _requestCert: true,
        _rejectUnauthorized: true,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        _idleNext: null,
        _idlePrev: null,
        _idleTimeout: -1,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 58,
        [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 608 },
     connection:
      TLSSocket {
        _tlsOptions: [Object],
        _secureEstablished: true,
        _securePending: false,
        _newSessionPending: false,
        _controlReleased: true,
        _SNICallback: null,
        servername: 'horizon-testnet.stellar.org',
        npnProtocol: undefined,
        alpnProtocol: false,
        authorized: true,
        authorizationError: null,
        encrypted: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 9,
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: null,
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'horizon-testnet.stellar.org',
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: false,
        domain: null,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _bytesDispatched: 592,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: undefined,
        _server: null,
        ssl: null,
        _requestCert: true,
        _rejectUnauthorized: true,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        _idleNext: null,
        _idlePrev: null,
        _idleTimeout: -1,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 58,
        [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 608 },
     _header: 'POST /transactions HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nX-Client-Name: js-stellar-sdk\r\nX-Client-Version: 0.15.3\r\nUser-Agent: axios/0.18.0\r\nContent-Length: 311\r\nHost: horizon-testnet.stellar.org\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
     _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
     agent:
      Agent {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        defaultPort: 443,
        protocol: 'https:',
        options: [Object],
        requests: {},
        sockets: [Object],
        freeSockets: {},
        keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
        keepAlive: false,
        maxSockets: Infinity,
        maxFreeSockets: 256,
        maxCachedSessions: 100,
        _sessionCache: [Object] },
     socketPath: undefined,
     timeout: undefined,
     method: 'POST',
     path: '/transactions',
     _ended: true,
     res:
      IncomingMessage {
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: false,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 3,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        socket: [Object],
        connection: [Object],
        httpVersionMajor: 1,
        httpVersionMinor: 1,
        httpVersion: '1.1',
        complete: true,
        headers: [Object],
        rawHeaders: [Array],
        trailers: {},
        rawTrailers: [],
        upgrade: false,
        url: '',
        method: null,
        statusCode: 504,
        statusMessage: 'Gateway Timeout',
        client: [Object],
        _consuming: true,
        _dumped: false,
        req: [Circular],
        responseUrl: 'https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/transactions',
        redirects: [],
        read: [Function] },
     aborted: undefined,
     timeoutCb: null,
     upgradeOrConnect: false,
     parser: null,
     maxHeadersCount: null,
     _redirectable:
      Writable {
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _options: [Object],
        _ended: true,
        _ending: true,
        _redirectCount: 0,
        _redirects: [],
        _requestBodyLength: 311,
        _requestBodyBuffers: [],
        _onNativeResponse: [Function],
        _currentRequest: [Circular],
        _currentUrl: 'https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/transactions' },
     [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]:
      { accept: [Array],
        'content-type': [Array],
        'x-client-name': [Array],
        'x-client-version': [Array],
        'user-agent': [Array],
        'content-length': [Array],
        host: [Array] } },
  response:
   { status: 504,
     statusText: 'Gateway Timeout',
     headers:
      { 'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0',
        'content-type': 'application/problem+json; charset=utf-8',
        date: 'Thu, 15 Aug 2019 08:25:20 GMT',
        vary: 'Origin',
        'x-ratelimit-limit': '101',
        'x-ratelimit-remaining': '100',
        'x-ratelimit-reset': '1',
        'content-length': '310',
        connection: 'Close' },
     config:
      { adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
        transformRequest: [Object],
        transformResponse: [Object],
        timeout: 60000,
        xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
        xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
        maxContentLength: -1,
        validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
        headers: [Object],
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/transactions',
        data: 'tx=AAAAAO6dqZWvM8smCFbXvnceXkb4OfCRjVxF1BwPz9hkEHlfAAAAyAADiukAAAABAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAF1VFzMAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAGAAAAAkFzdHJvRG9sbGFyAAAAAADCpKTKB1QZ83KqY5yS1pJuBj%2FkizTq9IfSurr4axwabAAAAAJUC%2BQAAAAAAAAAAAFkEHlfAAAAQHGAvUrL7Lj1veTs2YEAV3ZkccixLYdl6Z3ZIJveuk2x32YWqhHOk3BCIcY8m4MpdO8nuHF%2BysVHwhD8P8jGLAQ%3D' },
     request:
      ClientRequest {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 6,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: true,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: false,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: false,
        _removedConnection: false,
        _removedContLen: false,
        _removedTE: false,
        _contentLength: null,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [Object],
        connection: [Object],
        _header: 'POST /transactions HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nX-Client-Name: js-stellar-sdk\r\nX-Client-Version: 0.15.3\r\nUser-Agent: axios/0.18.0\r\nContent-Length: 311\r\nHost: horizon-testnet.stellar.org\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
        _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
        agent: [Object],
        socketPath: undefined,
        timeout: undefined,
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/transactions',
        _ended: true,
        res: [Object],
        aborted: undefined,
        timeoutCb: null,
        upgradeOrConnect: false,
        parser: null,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        _redirectable: [Object],
        [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object] },
     data:
      { type: 'https://stellar.org/horizon-errors/timeout',
        title: 'Timeout',
        status: 504,
        detail: 'Your request timed out before completing.  Please try your request again. If you are submitting a transaction make sure you are sending exactly the same transaction (with the same sequence number).' } } }
```

Thanks in anticipation, if anyone can help ?

Comment: https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/2716/should-testnet-be-rate-limited

Answer (score 2):

Since the testnet is getting flooded with transactions I would recommend setting a longer time bound on your transaction to see if that helps - yours is currently set to 100 seconds.

There's some documentation on that here: https://stellar.github.io/js-stellar-sdk/TransactionBuilder.html

Comment: I set the timeouts to 1,000 seconds, and it made no difference. I also set the fees to 20,000, again no difference. Even with timeouts of 1000 seconds, the error (504) came up after 2 minutes each time (i.e. roughly 120 seconds). Any other thoughts ? Thanks - Mark