# Where to send a suggestion to rate limit testnet?

Tags: testnet

It appears to be under a DOS attack, or abusive usage

It is clearly mentioned here: https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/test-net.html that Testnet should not be used for stress or load testing, but since a few days it stays stuck at 100% usage for long periods of time. It seems improbable that this is the result of "reasonable" usage, it's been running smoothly for months.

It would suck if reasonable users would have to run their own testnet for running minimalist unit tests. Something like an nginx reverse proxy with some rate limiting config could be all it takes to prevent such abuse https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/

The transactions monopolizing testnet all look like the following:

```
RECENT OPERATIONS: TEST NETWORK API
Source  Operation   Details Time ago
GCKO    payment 0.0000001 XLM » GBLH    4s
GCFG    payment 0.0000001 XLM » GBLH    4s
GDX4    payment 0.0000001 XLM » GBLH    4s
GCN4    payment 0.0000001 XLM » GBLH    4s
GATA    payment 0.0000001 XLM » GBLH    4s
GDZU    payment 0.0000001 XLM » GBLH    4s
GDMS    payment 0.0000001 XLM » GBLH    4s
GBNZ    payment 0.0000001 XLM » GBLH    4s
GAZQ    payment 0.0000001 XLM » GBLH    4s
GB5W    payment 0.0000001 XLM » GBLH    4s
GDLZ    payment 0.0000001 XLM » GBLH    4s
GARS    payment 0.0000001 XLM » GBLH    4s
GAQF    payment 0.0000001 XLM » GBLH    4s
GAH7    payment 0.0000001 XLM » GBLH    4s
GABR    payment 0.0000001 XLM » GBLH    4s
GB24    payment 0.0000001 XLM » GBLH    4s
GBAB    payment 0.0000001 XLM » GBLH    4s
GDUT    payment 0.0000001 XLM » GBLH    4s
GDQX    payment 0.0000001 XLM » GBLH    4s
GBDY    payment 0.0000001 XLM » GBLH    4s
```

Technical issues, bugs, etc are usualy submited via github issues, not sure if that's the proper channel in this case, it's not a bug...

Comment: We have no control over Testnet.  You should make such requests to them directly.

Comment: of course... there doesn't seem to be a channel for submiting these kinds of issues, perhaps that's the actual issue, I changed the title...

Comment: Given the change, I've reopened the question.

Comment: If you aren't a part of it already, we have a Stellar Keybase team (https://keybase.io/team/stellar.public) and a dev discussion channel for things like this.